# Confusion about the horizontal pressure gradient force being equal to the gradient of the geopotential in pressure coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, atmospheric-science, meteorology

I see many sources in atmospheric dynamics express the following:

$\frac{1}{\rho}(\nabla p) = \nabla_p \phi$

For example [this source](https://pog.mit.edu/src/810/pressure_coordinates.pdf) equation 10.

The reasoning given is that $\frac{1}{\rho}(\frac{\partial p}{\partial x})_z = (\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x})_p$ and $\frac{1}{\rho}(\frac{\partial p}{\partial y})_z = (\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y})_p$. (see equation 9 in my linked pdf).

---

While I agree with the above, shouldn't $\nabla_p \phi$ lie in a different plane that the $\nabla p$? The first should lie in the plane $p=const$ and the second should lie in the plane $z=const$.

Informally the $i$ and $j$ unit vectors should be different for these two gradients since we are in different coordinate systems. While I agree that the magnitudes attached to these gradients is indeed the same, the would be a bit tilted from each other?

I'm probably just missing something, and would appreciate some clarity, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> The first should lie in the plane =
> and the second should lie in the plane =

Yes …  the gradient of pressure is calculated on height planes while the gradient of Geopotential height is calculated on pressure plane.

> Informally the  and  unit vectors should be different for these two gradients since we are in different coordinate systems.

No both are sharing the same horizontal coordinate system …

Comment: The direction of the x coordinate system is orthogonal to the vertical vector so the horizontal coordinates are slightly different in terms of the direction they point in depending on the vertical coordinates. This is my understanding at least.

Comment: In both cases you are using the same Cartesian coordinate. To feel a change in the unit vector you have to use a coordinate different than the Cartesian

Comment: Also, note that the gradient used above is the horizontal gradient and the gradient direction depends on the tan of y/x see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_gradient